# ldloc var vs. ldloc.n

Tags: cil, intermediate-language

Do someone know if there is even a small difference using `ldloc var` CIL instruction and `ldloc.n` ?

Considering this local var table in a method scope :

```
.locals init ([0] int32 a,
              [1] int32 b)
```

Are those instructions:

```
ldloc.0
ldloc.1
```

better, worste or equal than:

```
ldloc a
ldloc b
```

Comment: The `ldloc var` is just sugar syntax for `ldloc.n` in ilasm.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a performance impact to create more than 4 local variables since ldloc.n is right for 0 <= n <= 3...

Comment: `ldloc n` can take any number. The `.` version is just the short version of it. Apparently slightly more efficient...

Comment: Yeah they are just 1 byte version, versus the 3 byte version opcode+short. It use to be that functions with 16 bytes or less of cil would be inlined.

Comment: could you please give more details about inlining in this context ?

Comment: I was wrong it was 32 bytes that was the usual jit limit. This article mentions more details about it.
http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/aggressive-inlining-clr-45-jit

You can now use a `methodattribute` to try to force inlining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many shortened forms of common opcodes with a simple goal - to shorten the length of the method. `ldloc.n` instructions take up one byte, `ldloc.s n` two bytes, and `ldloc n` three bytes. This is useful for inlining, as methods longer than 16 bytes are not eligible for it.